# How to convert a panel bar chart to multi-line chart in tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I am trying to create multi-line subplots such that each subplot represents a rating factor on which firms are rated, and each line represents a firm's change in rating over time. Note that I don't have the date field. I have a string field that says which quarter of the year the Mean of ratings belong to.

I'm new to tableau and I created something like this:
[image: my plot]

I want to create multiple subplots: one subplot for each of the 8 rating features in the above diagram, and the subplot has multiple lines representing the variation over time for each company. I have 10 companies.

Please guide me on how to achieve this?

A rough sketch of how I Imagine the plot to look like is below:
[image: my imagination]

Comment: Building the panel chart is a little tricky in Tableau. Not terribly hard once you understand table calcs. I suggest starting simpler by moving Measure Names from the Rows shelf to the Pages shelf, then creating the line charts you want - 1 per page. Then learn about table calc partitions and addressing, including “At the Level”   to have the info needed to define the panels

Comment: Moving it to pages made it so much better. Bit how do I convert it to a line chart? 
My X axis is not a time feature/ a number, "show me " doesn't allow me to choose it. Im not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1):

This will teach you how to make a panel chart in Tableau: https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/build-a-dynamic-panel-chart-in-tableau/

It shouldn't to too complex for what you're attempting (fingers crossed!).

Answer (score 0):

Building the panel chart is a little tricky in Tableau. Not terribly hard once you understand table calcs. I suggest starting simpler by moving Measure Names from the Rows shelf to the Pages shelf, then creating the line charts you want - 1 per page. Then learn about table calc partitions and addressing, including “At the Level” to have the info needed to define the panels

To make a colored line chart,

1. You need one field on columns that you set to display as continuous, making it green. If it is a date field, right click on the field and choose from the second set of groups, like month or quarter.
2. You need a continuous field on the Rows shelf, use Measure Values in your case
3. Use a discrete field on color to determine the number of lines, say Shortname
4. Set the Mark Type to either Automatic or line